# What is the cleanest way of implementing cancancan on my index.html.erb in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just wondering what everyone recommends doing for using cancan in their .html pages?

Just a little info on what I currently have set up...
My /app/models/ability.rb:

```
 user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
 if user.admin?
   can :manage, :all
 else
   can :read, :all
 end
```

I am using an articles_controller.rb and I set up an article model.

I am using the load_and_authorize_resource method in my articles_controller.rb

So onto my index.html.erb.

I have some CRUD options on my page and I only want some links and options such as edit and delete to be visible to the admin user.

In one part of my index.html.erb I have this link which can only be viewed by the admin.

```
<% if can? :create, @article %>
<%= link_to 'Post New Load Data!', new_article_path %>
<% end %>
```

^ This is perfect for what I want.

But I have another area on my index.html that confuses me.  It goes something like this...

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= article.title %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'View', article_path(article) %> |</td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %> |</td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article),
             method: :delete,
             data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
<p>
</table>
<% else %>
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= article.title %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'View', article_path(article) %> |</td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
  <% end %>
```

So it allows Admin to see the Edit and Delete options.
This is what I want but I am not using CanCan to do this.  Is there a 
way to simplify this using CanCan?  That way I don't have to repeat a lot of 
my sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to stick with devise's current_user.admin? because it reads nicely:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Title</th>
 </tr>

 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= article.title %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'View', article_path(article) %> |</td>
   <% if current_user.admin? %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %> |</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   <% end %>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```